# Python simple string formatting error

Tags: python, string

This is my script which is supposed to parse a list of domains (each seperated by returns) in a .txt file, separate them into individual domain names, send a request to a whois site with the domain name, check the response to see if it is available, and if it is, write it to a new file. so i get a list of only available names.

**The problem? It's pretty simple i just dont know the language well enough, I dont know how to get the domain name in a string format so that the request to the whois site is like this :**

http://whois.domaintools.com/google.com

Apparently the %s thing is not working.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2, urllib
print "Domain Name Availability Scanner."
print "Enter the Location of the txt file containing your list of domains:"
path = raw_input("-->")

wordfile = open(path, "r")
words = wordfile.read().split("n")
words = map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), words)
wordfile.close()

for word in words:
    req = urllib2.Request("http://whois.domaintools.com/%s") % (word)
    source = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    if "This domain name is not registered" in source:
    f = open("success.txt", "a")
    f.write("%s\n") % (word)
    f.close()
  break
```

error in terminal:

```
python domain.py
Domain Name Availability Scanner.
Enter the Location of the txt file containing your list of domains:
-->a.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "domain.py", line 13, in <module>
    req = urllib2.Request("http://whois.domaintools.com/%s") % (word)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'instance' and 'str'
```

Comment: Did you try reading the error message? Do you understand what it means?

Answer (score 5):

**Fix the parentheses:**

```
req = urllib2.Request("http://whois.domaintools.com/%s" % (word))
```

As well as:

```
f.write("%s\n" % word)
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
req = urllib2.Request("http://whois.domaintools.com/%s" % word)
# ...
f.write("%s\n" % word)
```

Comment: @SteveTjoa there was only one way to fix it :)

Comment: Wow yea I was typing mine and I hit submit and there were two already

Comment: Same here :DDDD I'll just +1 all :)

Comment: thanks guys, this fixed the error! i am learning python syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
f.write("%s\n" % word)
```

Check out this link, it should explain how this formatting works: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html